# What replaced the play.mvc.Mailer playframewrok in 2.0.3?

Tags: email, playframework-2.0

In the documentation for version 1.1 of Play Framework has the quote to *play.mvc.Mailer*, which I found very interesting:
http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/emails#mvc
But I'm using version 2.0.3 and want to use the same method, but did not find the class *play.mvc.Mailer*. Does anyone know why it was removed and has been replaced something?
Hug!

Answer (score 1):

In Play 2.x, it has been replaced by the [Typesafe Email plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer).